# Execute single workflow instance in parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, workflow-foundation-4, parallel-extensions

Let's say I have a workflow, and I want to execute it many times in parallel:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(
    0, 
    100, 
    i => WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(
        new Workflow1(),  
        new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Num", i } }));
```

I wonder, is it legal to execute it this way:

```
var w = new Workflow1();
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(
    0, 
    100, 
    i => WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(
        w, 
        new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Num", i } }));
```

Comment: Did you try this at all?

Comment: I'd be wary of doing anything if the documentation doesn't specifically say it is thread safe.

Comment: Yes I tried, but my test workflow was pretty simple. Although it worked correctly in my case, I am not sure whether it's safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is "legal" to execute a workflow definition that way. The workflow definition itself is thread safe as far as invocation goes. In fact, [it is highly recommended you always cache the workflow definition for reuse in your apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/02/12/wf4-performance-tip-cache-activities.aspx). This is because the definition is just a template for the execution, the execution itself results in an entirely new state each time.